# How can I create a custom builtType in gradle for android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I want to create a buildTask that I can use as "gradlew someTask" from the terminal. I basically want to do a few things before I run the build ( like changing versionCode and versionName ). I've tried a few solutions:

```
someTask.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
someTask{
 ...
}
```

Doing that, I get no errors while performing a gradle sync but when I run `gradlew someTask`, it give me an error "someTask not found in project root" and when I run `gradlew tasks`, someTask does not show up in the list either.
How can I fix this?

Any Help is Appreciated. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

These Gradle tutorials for writing custom task can be helpful to you.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

https://github.com/ysoftdevs/gradle-training

OReilly tutorials :  https://github.com/gradle/oreilly-gradle-book-examples/tree/master/tasks-custom-task-buildsrc

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to define your task

```
task myCustomTask << {
    // Put task code here
}
```

Usage : gradlew myCustomTask